# wso2 BAM hive ExecDriver error

Tags: wso2

Installed WSO2 BAM and AM today and I'm trying to get the API usage statistics to work. I can submit API requests that get authenticated and passed through correctly, but no statistics.

From API UI when I go to Statistics I get:

"No data found. Check BAM server connectivity ..."

The BAM server is up and running and I can login to it.

However in the BAM logs I see this:

```
ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Exception: Cannot run program "C:\Program" (in directory "C:\Temp\wso2\wso2bam-2.3.0"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
```

It looks like BAM is trying to launch something in "Program Files" but didn't escape the command properly in windows. (I suspect Java, since JAVA_HOME is pointing to a sub-directory of Program Files.)

I'm using BAM 2.3.0, AM 1.4.0 with JDK 1.7 on Windows 7.

Would this be why there is no data? Is there a workaround to the escaping issue?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

To run [BAM in windows](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM220/Introduction+to+BAM+Analytics+Framework) you need to install, Cygwin tool. If you have linux OS, run BAM in linux.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, tried double quoting the JAVA_HOME variable however BAM then through out the following on startup

```
Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45"" was unexpected at this time.
```

Only solution I found was to re-install java into a directory without spaces

Note - Am using version 2.0.1 of BAM

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with WSO2 BAM 2.4.0.

Also linked with the path to JDK.
For me, no need to reinstall the JDK but just change the JAVA_HOME environment variable to use the short version of the path (C:\Progra~1\Java... instead of C:\Program Files\Java...).

Cygwin is installed for me in a path with no space c:\cygwin. Did not test if this is mandatory. Be also sure to install all the cygwin package required in the WSO2 documentation.

regards,